# PHP 5.6 calling multiple class methods with class name as variable string

Tags: php, string, class, eloquent, php-5.6

I have a class name as a string variable (it is actually an eloquent model class name)

```
class Base_controller{
    public modelClassName = 'Product';
}
```

I would like to call this model's methods with parameters

```
class Base_controller{

    public modelClassName = 'Product';

    public function index(){

        $fields= 'id, name, price';

        $this->modelClassName::select($fields)->get();
    }
}
```

When I call the index function, I got an error :

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM) in ...
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: sorry, but you're really still using PHP 5.6? Upgrade to PHP 7.3.x.

Comment: The PHP 7 method should work in 5.3 or higher, so it should work in 5.6.

Comment: And in either case, there's no difference in how you call `get()`, you still put `->get()` at the end.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for your reply, you are correct, but i asked a wrong question :) So in my case the class name is a class's property, and in this scenario it doesn't work. (I edited the question)

Comment: Try `${$this->modelClassName}::select`. Or you can just write `$modelClassName = $this->modelClassName;`, and then use your original syntax.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you, your second example works like a charm :))) The `${$this->modelClassName}::select()...` says  `Undefined variable: Product`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the value of the class property to an ordinary variable, then use variable function calling syntax.

```
class Base_controller{

    public modelClassName = 'Product';

    public function index(){

        $fields= 'id, name, price';
        $class = $this->modelClassName;
        $class::select($fields)->get();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `call_user_func` if you like.

```
public function index()
{
    $fields = 'id, name, price';
    call_user_func([$this->modelClassName, 'select'], $fields)->get();
}
```